# Using the Kronos api to add training courses to a user?

Tags: php, xml, httprequest, kronos-workforce-central

I am attempting to use the Kronos api to add training courses to a user. I am not having any problems opening up a line of communication with the server, logging in, making (other) valid requests, and getting valid, expected results.

What I am having problems doing is finding any useful documentation for the xml string I need to send to the server to add training courses to an employee's profile. I've found information to add skills, certifications, and education, but not training. I've done extensive reading and searching on the documentation on Kronos' website, as well as posting a question there. I've googled this for the last three days, and I'm pretty sure this is possible, just can't find the proper documentation.

Any Kronos experts around here? It sure would be nice to get pointed in the right direction!

edit: we are using Workforce Connect v6.2

Comment: Please consult Kronos support. Which support options do they offer you? Which of those have you used so far? Which didn't work out? What does their staff say to your problem?

Comment: Their staff tells me to consult the documentation, which I already have.  We have pretty good support as far as using the gui, but they don't support the writing of third-party applications, without a fee.  Which might be the route we have to go.  I don't need a lot of help, I just need pointed in the right direction...

Comment: What are you using to communicate with the Kronos API? There isn't a lot of public documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a clear cut answer from Kronos on this...  Posting an answer in case anyone else stumbles across this problem.

According to Kronos, there is no way to do this via the API.  There solution is to enter training manually (which is what we were trying to avoid), or work with Kronos Professional Services to have a custom solution crafted, for a fee (which we are investigating).